# Cannot POST /updatedata

Tags: node.js, express

1.I am trying to modify my data in mysql database but getting error

2. I am able to add the data but unable to modify the data.
3. I have created a seperate tab in main page as modify.
   What changes needs to be done?

```
**var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'mr',
    port: '3308',
});
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});
app.get('/update', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/modify.html');
});
app.put('/updatedata',function(req,res){
    
    connection.query('update hp set Name=?,Address=?,Country=?,Phone=? where Id=?',[req.body.Name,req.body.Address,req.body.Country,req.body.Phone,req.body.Id],function(error,results,fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Record updated");
        res.redirect('/home');
    });
});
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});
app.listen(5000);
console.log('Server Started');**
```

Comment: The message  `record updated`  is logged? Are there any errors? Have you tried to check if database data is updated? Can you share code from html to update data?

Comment: Thank you @Danizavtz however was able to figure out had to add the below code-

app.post('/update',function(req,res){
    var Name=req.body.Name;
    var Address=req.body.Address;
    var Country=req.body.Country;
    var Phone=req.body.Phone;
    var id=req.body.id;

Comment: You can post a answer to your question. This will help others in same situation

Answer (score 0):

The title indicates you do a POST on `/updatedata`, but you define the PUT method for `/updatedata` in your code. Try to replace `app.put('/updatedata'` with `app.post('/updatedata'`.